# Parsing a huge plain text file

Tags: java, parsing, file-io, plaintext

I have a huge text file (207 MB, 4 million lines) and I need to read it sequentially line by line. 
Every line has this format: 
    `20227993821NAME AND SURNAME       NINIC NN08` 
I was using (for regular files) the Java library's `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` like this:

```
FileReader dataFile = new FileReader(directory);
data = new BufferedReader(dataFile);
String s;
while((s = data.readLine()) != null){
    //do stuff
}
```

with no problems, but with huge files it takes too much time to process.
I wonder what would be the best practice in such cases (another library, different methods, etc.), anything would be helpfull.
The file is issued periodically by a government agency and it must be loaded in to my software for data comparison.

Edit:

This code:

```
BufferedReader data = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String s;
int count = 0;
while ((s = data.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println (count + " - " + s);
   count++;
}
data.close();
```

executed in 19 minutes 30 seconds. I don't know why it took so long. 
I have a 64 bit operative system and a i5 processor.

Comment: Please define "too much time to process". How long does it take? Are you sure the time is spend in `java.io`?

Comment: Could you show us some more of your "do stuff" code? Did you try reading the file line by line without doing anything? Most likely, the reading is as fast as it gets; it's the processing that slows you down.

Comment: I'm parsing lines with around 20 million rows (around 2 gigs) in a matter of seconds. Chances are the problem is not in the java IO but rather in what you do with the data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I run

```
File file = new File("/tmp/deleteme.txt");
file.deleteOnExit();

long start = System.nanoTime();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
for (int i = 0; i < 4 * 1000 * 1000; i++)
    pw.println("01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789");
pw.close();

long mid = System.nanoTime();
BufferedReader data = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String s;
while ((s = data.readLine()) != null) {
    //do stuff
}
data.close();
long end = System.nanoTime();

System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to write and %.3f seconds to read a %.2f MB file.%n",
        (mid - start) / 1e9, (end - mid) / 1e9, file.length() / 1e6);
```

it prints

```
Took 0.465 seconds to write and 0.522 seconds to read a 204.00 MB file.
```

EDIT: If I print out each line, it slows down dramatically because writing to the screen take a long time.  I have found the MS-DOS window to be especially slow.

```
Took 0.467 seconds to write and 10.254 second to read a 204.00 MB file.
```

I don't believe its the reading of the file which is taking too long, it is what you are doing with it that is taking a long time.

Comment: How long does it take if you redirect the output to a file.  Some consoles (esp MS-DOS) are very slow.

Comment: Yeah, your right! the MS-DOS console slows down the whole process. I tried without SOUT and worked like a charm. Thanks for your help!